# Android Virtual Device is not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a problem with my Eclipse since I updated it to version 23.0.2. I am not able to create a virtual device to test my apps. I found a solution on Stack Overflow that says that I must create my Virtual Devices directly from AVD Manager (Not via Eclipse but via the file). So I succeed and created my virtual device. But when I open Eclipse and try to start my created virtual device, it doesn't work.

When I open AVD Manager directly from the source file everything seems OK as you can see below:

[image]

When I go back to Eclipse and open AVD Manager to activate a virtual device I see this:

[image]

The details of my virtual device called Test are as seen below:

[image]

Can someone see what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Comment: Did you tried creating AVD through eclispe ?

Comment: Yes, I filled in everything, it looks like the ok-button is disabled. It's unclickable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Unknown Target" means the relevant Android SDK isn't installed. Go to your SDK Manager and install the relevant SDK for the Android OS that was selected while creating the Virtual Device.

Answer (score 1):

The error says "Unknown Target android -15" . Do you have sdk android-15 in the android sdk on your PC?
If not, download it using the sdk manager.

Comment: I downloaded it. I have a new error that says: Missing system image for armeabi-v7a Android 4.0.3. Run 'android update avd -n test'

Comment: @user3608176 Again go to the SDK Manager and install that particular System Image, in this case  'ARM EABI v7a' , you can find this in the 'API 15' package.